# Cant mutate the state of a Slice Reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

When I try to set an item in the local storage it sets successfully therfore I've also written the logic in the reducer to set that item in the cart state also. problem is that ive set the initial state equal to the item in the local storage if any and it  gets that item initially also!! But it doesnt mutate the cart state on the go when I add one mor item.
Here is the code for my cart reducer

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";
let initialState = {
    cartItems: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart")) || [],
};

const CartReducer = createSlice({
    name: "cart",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        ADD_TO_CART(state, action) {
            const item = action.payload.product;
            //setting cart item into local Storage
            let cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart")) || [];
            const itemExist = cart.find((i) => i._id === item._id);
            if (itemExist) {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    cartItems: state.cartItems.map((i) =>
                        i._id === item._id ? item : i
                    ),
                };
            } else {
                cart.push(item);
                localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
            }
            //finished setting Local Storage

            if (state.cartItems[0]) {
                const itemExist = state.cartItems.find((i) => i._id === item._id);
                if (itemExist) {
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        cartItems: state.cartItems.map((i) =>
                            i._id === item._id ? item : i
                        ),
                    };
                } else {
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item],
                    };
                }
            }
        },
        ADD_TO_CART_RESET(state, action) {
            return {
                ...state,
                message: undefined,
            };
        },
    },
});

export const { ADD_TO_CART, ADD_TO_CART_RESET } = CartReducer.actions;
export default CartReducer;
```

`

I want when I dispatch addToCart action first it just adds the item in the local storage and also push that item in the cartsArray and mutate the state on runtime and when i refresh the page it just takes that all items from the local storage and sets The initial state, but actually only thing i cant do is that i cant mutate the state on clicking the action

Comment: Are you *sure* the state isn't updated? How are you verifying this? Do you have the redux dev-tools/extension installed so you can inspect the store and dispatched actions? Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: Thankyou brother! i solved that on my own ;) i just removed that initial state in the return statement in else condition after localStorage part